# Insert into database using onclick function

Tags: php, jquery

I'm developing a kind of question search engine based on Course wise, Subject wise by entering the keyword or question. 
Here I am querying the database based on search term against 3 tables namely `table_one`, `table_two`, and `table_three`. Code as follows

```
<?php
 if(isset($_GET['submit']))
 {
   $query = $_GET['query'];
   $query = htmlspecialchars($query);
   $query = mysqli_escape_string($link,$query);
   $searchTerms = explode(' ', $query);
   $searchTermBits = array();
   foreach ($searchTerms as $term) {
    $term = trim($term);
    if (!empty($term)) {
        $searchTermBits[] = "question LIKE '%$term%'";
    }
  }

 $subject_id = $_GET['subject'];
 $course_id = $_GET['course'];
 $min_length = 1;
 if(strlen($query) >= $min_length)
 {

  $res = "SELECT id,course_id,subject_id,question,option_a,option_b,option_c,option_d,option_e,correct_ans,fmge_year,contributor FROM table_one
WHERE (".implode(' OR ', $searchTermBits).") AND (`subject_id` LIKE '%".$subject_id."%') AND (`course_id` LIKE '%".$course_id."%')
UNION ALL
SELECT id,course_id,subject_id,question,option_a,option_b,option_c,option_d,option_e,correct_ans,fmge_year,contributor FROM table_two 
WHERE (".implode(' OR ', $searchTermBits).") AND (`subject_id` LIKE '%".$subject_id."%') AND (`course_id` LIKE '%".$course_id."%')
UNION ALL
SELECT id,course_id,subject_id,question,option_a,option_b,option_c,option_d,option_e,correct_ans,fmge_year,contributor FROM table_three 
WHERE (".implode(' OR ', $searchTermBits).") AND (`subject_id` LIKE '%".$subject_id."%') AND (`course_id` LIKE '%".$course_id."%')";

$raw_results = mysqli_query($link,$res) or die (mysqli_error());
if(mysqli_num_rows($raw_results) > 0)   
{
echo "<h3 style='text-align:center;color:#3366CC'><span style='color:#000000'>Search Results For : </span> $query </h3>";
while($results = mysqli_fetch_array($raw_results))
{
echo "<div class='content'>";
echo"<h4 id=".$results['id'].">" .preg_replace("/".preg_quote($query, "/")."/i", "<span class=\"highlight\">$query</span>", $results['question']) . "</h4>";
echo"<p id=".$results['id']."><span style='padding-left:20px'>option A : " .$results['option_a']."</span> <br><span style='padding-left:20px'> option B : ".$results['option_b']."</span><br/><span style='padding-left:20px'>option C : ".$results['option_c'].
"</span><br><span style='padding-left:20px'>option D : ".$results['option_d']."</span><br><span style='padding-left:20px'> option E : ".$results['option_e']."</span><br><span style='color:#253E66;font-weight:bold;padding-left:20px'>Correct Ans : ".$results['correct_ans']. 
"</span><br><span style='padding-left:20px'>Question Year : ".$results['question_year']."</span><br><span style='padding-left:20px'>Contributor : ".$results['contributor']."</span><br />
<a onclick=addQuestion('".$results['id']."') href='#'><span class='button'>Add to Question Bank</span></a></p>";
echo "</div>";
}
}
else{

echo "<span style='height:21px;syle=background-color: #F1F0FF;font-size:25px;color:#CC0000'>Your search - $query - did not match any queries.</span> ";
}
}
}
?>
```

I'm Calling the following addQuestion() function when i click the Add to Question Bank link.

```
    <script>
    function addQuestion(val)
    {
        var conf=confirm("Are you sure you want to add this question to Question Bank")

        if(conf){
             //Here I Want some code to update my database. 
              }
    }
</script>
```

The script above displaying confirmation box when i click the button, 
My Question is,
After confirmation I want to insert my question into the new table in the database and display message like "Question added" in front of the question permanently  as i know i can't write PHP inside Jquery function Any help may appreciated.

Comment: In your if(conf){ } block you can use jquery ajax and send data to serverfile and on is response you can easily display message question added.

Comment: Ok! So... What have you tried? Any errors or are you just begging us for some insert code?

Comment: As I am newbie, I have no aware about ajax, any code may helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by including the ajax. 
put the ajax code which may looks like the following:

```
if(conf){
    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "$$phpfilepath",
           data: {param:'$$value'},
           success: function(data) {
        // do the message display code
           }
       });
}
```

Don't forget to include the jquery cdn link in the head tag of the html page.

Answer (score 0):

you need to send an ajax request.
you need to send it either by a post or get method to a php script that will return json so you can be updated on the page with results.
the answer above has an example ajax script sent with a post method:
data needs to be sielized if you are submitting it via form or an array.

this should help you
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp
https://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Answer (score 0):

Onclick - You need to do that with ajax. So basically, you need PHP plus javascript involved. You can use Jquery of similar JS library for easy ajax support.

Just and example with jquery library version 1.11.2 how to include:

```
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

For example, if this is your input field you want to save and button for submitting:

```
<input id="title" name="title" />

<input type="submit" value="Save">
```

Change it to button and give it javascript save() function (can be any name you give).

`<input type="button" onclick="save($('#title').val());" value="Save">`

In this example, I added 1 param to that save function, which is supposed to grab a value from html input filed with id "title". 
On this page, there that html is, you need to include mentioned jquery(or similar) library and also include piece of javascript function for generating ajax request, which is named "save" here.

If you included jquery library, you must call javascript function for saving your data before your  tag:

```
<script type"text/javascript">
function save(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "yourpath/yourfile.php",
        data: {title: title},
        success: function(data) {
            alert("Ajax save executed!");
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

When javascript function you named save() will execute, it will send POST request to yourpath/yourfile.php

There, you can easily get your POST data by in yourpath/yourfile.php:

```
if(isset($_POST['title'])){ 
// do something with POST data, save in db.. (make sure to include security when inserting to db) 
}
```

If you want to send it with GET, you easily replace **POST** with **GET**:

```
function save(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
```

and also in .php file you write:

```
if(isset($_GET['title'])){ 
// do something with POST data, save in db.. (make sure to include security when inserting to db) 
}
```

Comment: I tried as follows but, Ajax code is not working                                     `<script type="text/javascript">
 function addQuestion(val)
 {
  var conf=confirm("Are you sure you want to add this question to Question Bank");
  
  if(conf){
       $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "localhost/my_folder/my_filename.php",
          data: {title: title},
          success: function(data) {
          alert("Ajax save executed!");
          }
      });
   }
 }
</script>`

Comment: data: {title: title} is wrong. You passed param named val. It shoud be then in this par like this:  data: {title: val}