# HTML Form isn't submitting. Using Material Desing and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have this form which I can't make submit.

```
<div class="enviar">
    <form onClick="submitForm();" id="MessageSend" name="MessageSend" method="post" action="Send_Text_Msg.php">
        <table width="100%">
            <tr width="100%">
                <td colspan="2"width="600px">
                    <textarea disabled="disabled" rows="4" name="MessageTextArea" id="MessageTextArea" style="resize: none;"></textarea>
                </td>               
                <td>
                    <div class="button raised blue" style="cursor: pointer;">
                        <div class="center" fit>Enviar</div>
                        <paper-ripple fit ></paper-ripple>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td><input type="submit" onclick="submitForm();"hidden id="IDConversa" name="IDConversa" value=""/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>
```

Since I'm using a < div > as a button I use this Javascript code to submit it

```
function submitForm()
{
    alert("hue");
    if(document.getElementById('MessageTextArea').value == "")
        return false;
    else
        document.getElementById('MessageSend').submit();
}
```

And the weird part is that even the alert() isn't showing up. I was using a normal button before this material design one and It wasn't working either

EDIT:

***I gave up on using form. I'll use AJAX instead. Thanks for the help***

Comment: dont do onclick on submit button but put it into the form instead

Comment: @daremachine but isn't the the button that is being clicked?

Comment: i think you want to validate your form and then submit? right

Comment: If you want to process form with ajax - you can easily:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29471074/insert-into-database-using-onclick-function/29471757#29471757

Comment: but this is jquery library not vanilla js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried it in jsfiddle. It seems you have script in bad order!!! If i modified your script as below it start work.

[tutorial w3c](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp)

Put your validatation script into head or on body. In jsfiddle left side no wrap .. option

Add onsubmit no onclick into the form

```
<form id="MessageSend" name="MessageSend" method="post" onsubmit="return submitForm()" action="Send_Text_Msg.php">
```

and it working fine

[DEMO JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7z4wLero/)

Comment: This was the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't write it like this:

```
</td>
<input hidden id="IDConversa" name="IDConversa" value=""/>
</tr>
```

Any html data in table should be in td's. Or put that hidden field outside table.

You should also avoid doing onclick on divs. Make an a tag, and put it there.

Comment: Put input submit field (type="submit" and put there onsubmit="something();" and remove unnecesary onclick methods from div and form (both have onclick). Paper-ripple is not a tag, remove that.